# Hide an element on several pages, what is wrong with my syntax?

Tags: css

It seems that the `display: none` is applied to the whole pages and not only .apss-social-share
Thanks

```
body.page-id-15425,
body.page-id-15206,
body.page-id-15246,
body.page-id-15423,
body.page-id-1452
.apss-social-share {
    display : none ;
}
```

Comment: you're missing a comma

Comment: In CSS, commas separate each and every selector that the following css rules will be applied to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`,` has lower precedence than the descendant combinator. This formatting might make what happens more obvious:

```css
body.page-id-15425,
body.page-id-15206,
body.page-id-15246,
body.page-id-15423,
body.page-id-1452 .apss-social-share {
    display : none ;
}
```

Specify `.apss-social-share` for each one:

```css
body.page-id-15425 .apss-social-share,
body.page-id-15206 .apss-social-share,
body.page-id-15246 .apss-social-share,
body.page-id-15423 .apss-social-share,
body.page-id-1452 .apss-social-share {
    display : none ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, commas separate each and every selector that the following css properties/values will be applied to. To make this totally clear:

```
selector1,
selector2,
selector3 .sub-element-class {
    display: none;
}
```

is identical to

```
selector1 {
    display: none;
}
selector2 {
    display: none;
}
selector3 .sub-element-class {
    display: none;
}
```

Variation 1 ist just shorter to write, especially if applying not only one but a larger amount of CSS properties.